# ABI encoding params/values length mismatch usePrepareContractWrite

Tags: wagmi, wagmi-hooks, wagmi-react

I am using wagmi-react hooks to write contract data. Everything works fine with the `useContractWrite()` but having this issue when using `usePrepareContractWrite()`

> ABI encoding params/values length mismatch. Expected length (params):
> 2 Given length (values): 0

This is the abi I am using for ERC721 NFTs

```
import { erc721ABI } from "wagmi";
   
 export const ContractConfig = {
        address: '0x07a06AD39f940a505B306b294b29390e792C3869', 
        abi: erc721ABI
    }
```

This is the `usePrepareContractWrite`

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        ...ContractConfig,
        functionName: 'setApprovalForAll',
    });
```

This is `useContractWrite`

const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config);

```
if (write) {
            write({
                args: [BatchTransferAddress, true],
                from: address
            })
        }
```